# Visual Studio gives errors yet Command line doesn't. Why?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, web-scraping, command-line

I have python code that runs fine and scrapes all the tables if I run it from the command line.  If I run the same code from Visual Studio it tells me many of the tables are missing.  How can this be?

Full Code

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlsxwriter

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
}


def scrape_finviz_data(version):
    url = f"https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v={version}&r={{page}}&f=all&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70&f=ind_stocksonly&o=-marketcap"

    page = 1

    screen = requests.get(url.format(page=page, version=version), headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(screen.text, features="lxml")
    pages = int(soup.find_all("a", {"class": "screener-pages"})[-1].text)

    data = []
    
    #for page in range(1, 200, 20):
    for page in range(1, 20 * pages, 20):  
        # print(version, page, url.format(page=page, version=version))
        screen = requests.get(
            url.format(page=page, version=version), headers=headers
        ).text
        tables = pd.read_html(StringIO(screen))
        data.append(tables[-2])

    return pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    version = "152"
    df = scrape_finviz_data(version)
    print(df)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Data.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook = writer.book
workbook.filename = 'Data.xlsm'
workbook.add_vba_project('./vbaProject.bin')
writer.close()
```

Visual Studio Errors

```
File "c:\Users\jkru0\OneDrive\Desktop\vince.py", line 30, in scrape_finviz_data
    tables = pd.read_html(StringIO(screen))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1245, in read_html
    return _parse(
           ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1008, in _parse
    raise retained
  File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 988, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 248, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 603, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found
```

Comment: Can you please execute the command which python in both command line and in the viscose terminal? Also, I would suggest outputting the screen variable for comparison.

Comment: For the command line, it's Python filename.py   For Visual Studio, I hit Control and F5.  Not sure what a screen variable is, sorry.

Comment: I mean, executing the command which python in the terminal (which python in unix OS, where python in Windows cmd). In Visual Studio check for python environment to see if it matches the with the first one. The screen variable is the one you are passing to the method pd.read_html(StringIO(screen)). It seems that visual studio is not getting the same content, so there you could start debugging the reasons.

Comment: as @HeriveltonAndreassa mentions,  make sure you are running the same python install in both cases.   if not you might have different versions of pandas and therefore it might parse the screen differently.

Comment: I'll put my bets on this being the working directory problem that a bunch of newbies run into.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should show everyone what your terminal commands look like. If you use `Ctrl+F5` to execute a script in vscode, which is `Run Without Debugging`,

[image]

its command may be like this:

[image]

And the configuration in **launch.json** will be used.

You should use **`Run Python File`**, which simply executes script files.

[image]